# How to reuse a dynmically generated fragement?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding

In the main fragment of my activity, I generate more fragments dependent on a config file.
When the device is rotated, I want to reuse the former generated fragments instead of creating them again.
This is the creation method, called in `onCreateView` of the main fragment:

```
private fun initChildFragments(elementsContainer: LinearLayout) {
    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    for (element in config.elements) {
        val id = element.id
        // create new container for fragment
        addElementContainer(elementsContainer, id)

        // try to re-use old fragment
        var fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(element.getTag())
        if (fragment == null) {
            // create new fragment (should only happen at first run)
            fragment = TestFragment.newInstance()
        }
        // add fragment to our container.
        transaction.replace(id, fragment, element.getTag()
    }

    transaction.commitNow()
}

private fun addElementContainer(container: LinearLayout, id: Int) {
    val childContainer = FrameLayout(context)
    childContainer.id = id
    container.addView(childContainer)
    // for test purposes to make the container visible
    val textView = TextView(context)
    textView.setText("ID: " + id)
    container.addView(textView)
}
```

When I first start the app, everything works fine. When I rotate the device, the fragments where found by findFragmentByTag and added to the containers. The element containers are visible on the screen (through the text view), but the fragments are not visible.

If I re-create the fragments every time the device rotates, they appear on the screen again, but then I loose all my ViewModel data.

Comment: "but then I loose all my ViewModel data" -- you are not using `ViewModel` in your question. If you are using `ViewModel` from the Architecture Components, it is retained for you across configuration changes, even if you go through the normal activity/fragment destroy-and-recreate cycle.

Comment: Yes, I am using ViewModels from architecture components. I get the ViewModels in my Fragments with ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TestFragmentVM::class.java). I can see that they are still there in the fragments found by "findFragmentById". My problem is that these fragments are not visible and if I create new ones, they are visible but does not have my view models, of course.